# Is Apache POI CellReference able to handle multiple another tab sheets in the same formula?

Tags: java, excel-formula, apache-poi, cell, worksheet

I have a cell formula that references multiple sheets
`('1 - Sheet'!$P:$P,'1 - Sheet'!$E:$E,'Another Calc'!$A10)`
When I try to instantiate a new CellReference object with my formula, Apache POI throws a error **Bad sheet name quote escaping** from *parseSheetName* method inside CellReference. This happens because the formula has multiple quotes and the method not handle this appropriately. Is there another way that CellReference can handle it or some kind of workaround to force CellReference handle appropriately?

I've already done some research on but the all scenarios that I found were always with just a single reference in formula to another sheet and in this case the Apache POI works correctly.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve. A `CellReference` is a reference to **one** cell. So `org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference cellReference = new org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference("'Another Calc'!$A10");` should work. There is `AreaReference` to reference a cell range. So `org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference areaReference = new org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference("'1 - Sheet'!$P:$P", org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);` should work too. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Gotcha what you mean. So there's no problem with how Apache POI handle the formula, but how is the formula is passing to CellReference constructor. Sorry about my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75173045/is-apache-poi-cellreference-able-to-handle-multiple-another-tab-sheets-in-the-sa#comment132654721_75173045) from [Alex Richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter) showed to me the problem was in how the formula was being passed to the `CellReference` constructor. I need change this, and Apache POI will work correctly.

> A `CellReference` is a reference to *one* cell, so this should work:

```
var cellReference = new
    org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference(
        "'Another Calc'!$A10");
```

> Alternatively, there is `AreaReference` to reference a cell *range*, so this should work too:

```
var areaReference = new
    org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference(
        "'1 - Sheet'!$P:$P", org.apache.poi.ss
            .SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
```